# what is the actual curvature of earth, either per kilometer (km of sea-level distance, round, not straight line), either calculated

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

First of all, the following question with it's answers are the main reason I put this question, because as I will show the question wording is bad.
[How to calculate curvature of Earth per surface kilometer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1896238/how-to-calculate-curvature-of-earth-per-surface-kilometer)

Basic data: at a distance (ground distance, as in a ship on the sea) of aproximately 10.000 kilometers, the drop (h in that drawing) should be close to the radius of the earth (aproximately 6371 KM), for simplification we don't take into account the small differences resulting from the fact that Earth is not a perfect sphere! That is basic geometry (because it corresponds to 90 degrees from the sphere).

However with the complicated math in that question, the conclusion states there is a 8 cm per kilometer drop, which at 10.000 kilometers equals 80.000 cm, equals 800 meters???
Isn't it surrealistic to have a drop of only 800 meters at a distance of 10.000 kilometers?

If after 2, 3, 10, 2000 km (random values) and so on, the drop per kilometer is another value, it means the linked question is bad-worded **(per surface kilometer would mean a constant value, not a non-linear one)...** I added this paragraph after @zabop's comment
This bad-wording is present in many sites and leads to confusion, as there is no easy way to calculate the h drop for any given distance.

I also found this resource, but the formula there is for straight line distance:
http://www.revimage.org/what-is-the-curvature-of-earth-per-km/

The excel formula in the second link is good to calculate the drop for any **straight line** distance between 0 and 6371 km (after a distance equivalent to more than 90 degrees the h would no longer make sense):
h, or X in the link, =3959-(3959*(COS(ASIN(L/3959))))
{or the equivalent in kilometers, instead of 3959 there would be ~6371}

Later edit
I just found another drawing, now I think the diagram in [this link](http://www.ringbell.co.uk/info/hdist.htm) is actually what I was looking for (the v value in the diagram below), as in the first examples the h line is not perpendicular to the earth, but to the line representing the imaginary straight distance, so don't think it's accurate enough.
[better version diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz9VT.gif)
Note: the diagram is good, but the calculations use the straight line distance (O in the diagram), so one problem solved but another created.
**It would be good to have a formula for this case, to calculate v using circular distance.**

Another case (a tall object that would still be visible beyond sea-level horizon line) [here](https://www.cactus2000.de/uk/unit/masshor.shtml)

**What would an excel formula for sea-level distance (round distance, not straight line) be?**

Comment: You can't just multiply up because your what you call horizontal is changing too. 8 cm per km doesn't mean 8000 cm for 1000 km. Try drawing it and that will make understanding easier.

Comment: @zabop Hmm... Thanks I added a paragraph to use a different wording (per surface kilometer would mean a constant value, so the first question might be bad-worded). Anyway I'm too basic at math to check if the second link gives a good excel formula or not.

Comment: Read again the link you provided. It states clear that the relation distance-drop is **not linear**. Using aproximations is only valid when distance is a small number related to Earth radius.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thanks, I reformulated and added the final question, as I just want to calculate h value for any distance up to 10.000 km (90 degree surface distance equivalent): What would an excel formula for sea-level distance (round distance, not straight line) be?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct to suggest there is no answer of the form $x$ centimetres *per kilometre*. The formula $\ d=ks^2\ $, where $\ d\ $ is the "drop" in centimetres, $\ s\ $ the linear distance along the Earth's surface in kilometres, and  $k=7.848$cm per kilometre *squared*, however, does give a reasonably good approximation for distances up to about  the radius of the Earth, and is quite accurate for *relatively short* distances.  Here's a comparison of the true value of the drop and the $7.848\text{cm/km}^2\ $ estimate for various distances (with the radius, $\ R_e\ $, of the Earth taken to be $6371$km) :
\begin{array}{c|c|c|}
\text{distance }s\text{ (km)}&{\text{ true drop }\left(R_e-R_e\cos\frac{s}{R_e}\right)}&7.848\text{cm/km}^2\text{ approximation}\\
\hline
1&7.848\text{cm}&7.848\text{cm}\\
\hline
10&7.848\text{m}&7.848\text{m}\\
\hline
100&784.8\text{m}&784.8\text{m}\\
\hline
1000&78.32\text{km}&78.48\text{km}\\
\hline
6371\ (R_e)&2929\text{km}&3185\text{km}\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: I have done an LibreOffice Calc formula for both answers, for this is =6371-6371*COS(s/6371). I'm not very good at math and I hope that the sintagm per "kilometre squared" doesn't mean an area, as this calculations should be in a single plan/2D section, but areas would mean 3D.

Comment: On rereading my answer, I found I initially misunderstood it myself, so I've now rewritten part of it to make it clearer where the cm per kilometre squared comes from.  The main point however is that the approximation not *linear*, but *quadratic*, in $\ s\ $.   That is, if $\ s\ $ is raised by a factor of $10$ the drop is raised by a factor of $100$, not just $10$.

Comment: Oh, and you're correct that the kilometre squared has nothing to do with surface area. It's simply a fact that if $\ s\ $ is specified in units  of kilometres, then $\ s^2\ $ has units of kilometres squared, so if you want the answer $\ d\ $ to have units of centimetres, then the constant multiplying $\ s^2\ $ *must* have units of centimetres per kilometre squared,

Answer (score 0):

I will use the same image as in your link.

Horizontal distance (straight): $H$

Arc length (round distance): $s$

Earth radius; $R=6371$ km

"Drop" (vertical): $h$

Formulas to operate with:

$H= R·\sin(\theta)$

$h= R·(1-\cos(\theta))$

$s= R·\theta$

If $H$ and $R$ are the data, then we need how to calculate $s$, by calculating $\theta$:

$\sin(\theta)= \frac{H}{R}\implies\theta= \arcsin\left(\frac{H}{R}\right)$

and then

$s=\;R·\arcsin\left(\frac{H}{R}\right)$

$h= R·\left(1-\sqrt{1- \sin^2(\theta)}\right)\;=\;R·\left(1-\sqrt{1- \left(\frac{H}{R}\right)^2}\right)$

These formula are valid for $H<R$. Beyond that, the "drop" falls out of Earth, it's taken as "vertical" not as perpendicular to the circle.

Comment: Thanks, now I'll find some day to translate that in an excel formula, and then accept this answer. If someone knows faster than me to do the translation, that would be great.

Comment: @Dan In practice we generally measure the distance between distant objects along the surface of the Earth, which in my opinion makes all the parts involving $H$ and $\sin\theta$ not very useful. If you want an "exact" formula I would recommend the other answer's formula, $R_e-R_e\cos\frac{s}{R_e}.$

Comment: At a second look: the only way to find out θ (because I don't know H, I know only s) would be s divided by R. I guess @DavidK is right, but I wanted to verify that against your formula.

Comment: I have done an LibreOffice Calc formula for both answers, for this is h=6371*(1-SQRT(1-(POWER(SIN(s/6371), 2)))) assuming sin to power 2 * (θ) is the same with sin*(θ) to power 2 (sorry I'm not good at math). And for various s values it gives the same results as the other answer, but the other answer is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Using lonza's answer I also created a LibreOffice Calc (excel maybe also works) formula (because I also formulated the need for an excel formula at the end of my question):

```
=6371-6371*COS(s/6371)
```

where you can change "s" for a cell that will contain the distance.